# How to call shellscript in java program?

Tags: java, linux

How to call shellscript in java program?

```
String sCommandString="sh /home/admin/ping.sh";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sCommandString);
```

Comment: here i want to check whether ip is reachable or not

Comment: so you need to pass an argument?

Comment: yes,i need to pass an argument paul

Comment: executed but no result shown ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplest way to run command and get ouput:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls");
p.waitFor();
Scanner s = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    String l = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println(l);
}
```

Comment: catch and print exception!

Answer (score 1):

Pass the IP in command. I think this should work:

```
String sCommandString="sh /home/admin/ping.sh 10.12.12.26<Any IP>";
```

Comment: can you share your ping.sh?

Comment: #!/bin/bash

ip=255.7.143.65

nmap -p 80 $ip

if [ $? = 0 ]

then

echo "Port is Reachable"

else

echo "Port is not Reachable"

fi

Comment: wait for 2  min, I will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Executing test.sh shellscript with passing param1 as parameter.Execute and wait for process to start and it will return int value 0 for successfully start of test.sh shellscript.

 Process process = null;
    try {
        int param1 =10;
        String[] command = {"sh", "-c", 'test.sh' + " " + param1};
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        logger.debug("Process started for [param1 : " + param1 + "]);

        int i = process.waitFor();
        process.getOutputStream().close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error while creating process. Full stack trace is as follows ", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (process != null) {
                process.getInputStream().close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Error while closing process. Full stack trace is as follows ", ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.